# Binding NSPopUpButton to NSArray

Tags: nsarray, nspopupbutton

I'm a little lost with bindings on `NSPopUpButton`. I have a custom class that holds an array of items that I'd like to display in a pop up. These items are subclasses of `NSManagedObject`s and they are contained in an `NSArray`. I don't want to use an `NSArrayController` since I've had lots of trouble changing the selection programmatically and it feels like cluttering the implementation.

The problem is simply that I don't know how to bind the array properly to the pop up. All I have managed to do is list the array items on the pop up menu, but the titles are core data URIs. I believe I could use the `description` method to change the title, but this does not sound very advisable.

Any ideas how to bind `NSArray` to the `NSPopUpButton` properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it. I simply created these bindings for `NSPopUpButton`:

1. "Content" to the `items` property (of type `NSArray*`)
2. "Selected Object" to `selectedItem` (of type `Item*`)
3. Finally "Content Values" to `items.name`

For the third binding I implemented `valueForKeyPath:`

```
- (id)valueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{
    NSArray *components = [keyPath componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"."]];
    if ([components count] == 2 && [components objectAtIndex:0] == @"items")
    {
        return [self.items valueForKey:[components objectAtIndex:1]];
    }
    return [super valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
}
```

The third binding could've been also a separate array for titles, but I this is much more flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it set me on the right path. I wanted to note that I have a class with a property (myinstance.items) that is an array of dictionaries.  I am able to display an NSPopupButton containing the values for the key:"name" in the dictionaries simply by binding Content to the array and Content Values to myinstnace.items.name.